# ASP.NET OData v3 controllers and OData v2 endpoint possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I recently implemented an OData v3 endpoint using VS and entity framework based on tutorials as ASP.NET beginner. I've just exposed several tables, working fine. Now I need to implement almost the same, but the client is able to manage OData v2 only. Is it possible to config simply the endpoint setting the DataServiceversion and MaxDataServiceVersion in WebApiConfig.cs like this ?

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.DataServiceVersion = new Version(2, 0);
builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = new Version(2, 0);
```

My current Controllers are of type ODataController. For OData v2 I found examples of the controllers of type ApiController.
Would it be possible to keep the v3 controllers, or do I need different controllers ?
Thank you